# Random integrity constraint errors saving orders in Magento 2.1 after payment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, sales-order

I have a system that generates quotes, then submits the quotes, which processes a payment.

The system is pretty standard: nothing really complicated is going on. `The quotes have a single product in them`.

After the payment is processed, Magento saves the Order and the payment. However, **sometimes we get an exception:**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sales_order_address`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

This error suggests to me that it is trying to save the `sales_order_address` for a non-existent sales_order record, but why would that happen?

The payment was **processed successfully on the backend** but there is nothing recorded in the database to indicate that. Retrying the same quote again with the same input data usually results in success - the error appears to be transient.

How can I figure out what is causing the sales_order record to be deleted? How is this even possible? I tried searching the Magento code for a transaction rollback that swallows an exception, but didn't find any. We are using a third-party Stripe payment module but the order-saving part happens after the payment was successfully placed. From what I can see whatever error is happening here is entirely in the core code.

The error is happening on the **latest (2.1.11) version.**

Comment: What is the 3rd party stripe payment module provider. Most likely the culprit is there. As it seems to be on the order address deletion cascade. Typically with exceptions around payment processing will re-attempt or continue on non-fatal exceptions for obvious reasons. Any code snippets around the stripe payment processing would help here. Also consider reaching out to the original vendor for latest versions/bug fixes changelog.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7691 & https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7689 a few possibly related 2.1.x bugs fixed in 2.2.x. My guess is this addition in 2.1.11 is causing the FK delete cascade issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/179f98416618ccf6afb7c50f10fd32fb7b98b856#diff-264ff89ba329be84d26a6c5377941a6aR117

Comment: I don't want to name the Stripe provider module because this problem happens after the payment is placed, never before. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with their code.

Comment: @B00MER We were having the issue in our previous version which was 2.1.6 (I think). So I don't think it's a recent change in 2.1.11 that introduced the problem.

Comment: The payment method handles a big part of the order process so it's likely that something missed in the payment method can contribute. Are you able to replicate the issue using any other payment method?

Comment: The problem happens maybe once or twice per 40,000 quotes processed and if we retry the same input data to recreate a quote it succeeds. The problem is always after the payment is processed, when saving the order.

Comment: If it's unreproducible in other environments & is just an edge case, while not ideal but being more verbose on logging of magento, the services stack & adding some additional custom  logging for a short time in order to catch the edge case scenario is most likely best approach. Blindly attempting fixes may do more harm than good. A good centralized logging system would be beneficial here as well. Just be cautious of high I/O when logging intensively.